# Change content of Meta-tags for IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got code as below. I want change content of Meta-tags IE=Edge. But this code only in browser"chrome", browser"IE11" inactive. The people help me, please!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
<script src="../js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $('meta[name=description]').remove();
        $('head').append( '<meta name="description" content="IE=Edge">' );; 
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

please you can see this page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

It forces the browser the render at whatever the most recent version's standards are. Just like using the latest version of jQuery on Google's CDN, this is the most recent, but also can potentially break your code since its not a fixed version.

Last, but not least, consider adding this little tidbit:

[See the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611264/x-ua-compatible-content-ie-9-ie-8-ie-7-ie-edge)

[Page 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275356/ie-compatibility-mode-x-ua-compatible-tag-edge)

Comment: Thanks @Ivin rai !! I tested for your case. But this page, i want to dynamic processing for Meta-tags. so i coded above. Have you new idea for this case?

Comment: ya if u like my answer please upvote and right option click sir@NguyenHongQuang