# how add margin-top style only for all version of ie

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

i want to add that for all version of IE (Version 6 to last one) only but nothing changes, i did something bad ?

UPDATED:

```
<!--[if IE]> <style type="text/css">.iemargin {margin-top:30px;}<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><style type="text/css">.iemargin {margin-top:30px;}<![endif]-->
```

Comment: please you can see this page:

[Page one][1]

[Page 2][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611264/x-ua-compatible-content-ie-9-ie-8-ie-7-ie-edge
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275356/ie-compatibility-mode-x-ua-compatible-tag-edge

Answer (score 1):

Conditional comments are supported [only in IE9 and below](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx) and not supported in IE10, IE11 or Edge. If you really need to detect browser you should use some javascript library like [this](https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin) (add this code in the end of file before  closing `</body>` tag):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-browser/0.0.8/jquery.browser.min.js">
<script>$('html').addClass($.browser.name);</script>
<style>.msie .iemargin {margin-top:30px;}</style>
```

1. Including jQuery. If you have it already you can skip.
2. The library that detects browser.
3. Adding class with browser name to `html` element on page.
4. Using class `.msie` to apply styles only to Internet Explorer.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/av5tw588/1/

Comment: so if i want a css for my div for all version of ie i can't right it directly on my html page, i need to create a css file ?

Comment: No, you can put it into your page but version 10+ of IE will ignore your conditional comment and not apply the style.

Comment: ah that's bad, so there's any solution to have a style css for all version ?

Comment: Added example of javascript based solution. Browser detection was a common thing years ago, so there was conditional comments and other things. Now all browsers works almost the same way so usually you don't need to detect browser.