# Bing maps v8 not loading for IE11

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm doing a pretty standard loading of a map, like:

```
 map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
```

In Chrome it works fine, but in IE11, I get an exception in the map code:

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'matchMedia'

The line within the Bing maps code is:

```
return window.matchMedia("(-ms-high-contrast:active)").matches
```

The window variable is defined, but if I examine it matchMedia is undefined.

The entire stack trace is:

```
Unhandled exception at line 1, column 9149 in https://www.bing.com/rms/MapCoreBundle/jc,nj/81a88ae6/9adb7eaf.js?bu=rms+answers+MapsSDK+AnonymousBegin*MapCore.en*MapCoreBegin*LabelOptions*LocalStorageCache*Gimme*GimmeWrapper*evPromise*ExternalPromise*StaticPromise*CookiesHelper*LruCache*Point*Rectangle*NAARectangle*ResourceManager*Units*Anchor*Size*Binding*ChangeMagnitude*EventBinding*Observable*ObservableObject*ObservableObjectChangedArgs*ObservableCollection*Debug*DelayLoadedObject*JSEvent*Dispatcher*WorkDispatcher*Iterator*ElementSizeHelper*GimmeExt*GimmeTransition*Helper*PerfState*ClientPerf*LoggingWrapper*LoggerConstants*Network*ThrottledEventInvoker*ObjectPool*StaticObjectPool*FixedSizeObjectPool*OrderedDictionary*PooledImage*Url*MapCoreMiddle*AltitudeReference*TransformCurve*GraphType*CurveKey*Curve*Color*CurveVector4*CurveColor*Vector4*CurveTangent*DiscreteRange*DiscreteRangeCollectionSpline*MapLayer*AutoScaling*PointLabelPlacementPreference*PolygonFillPreference*VerticalAlignment*CopyrightProvider*CopyrightProviderService*EntityState*MinZoomFraming*GeometryType*HitTestability*HorizontalAlignment*MapModeType*ViewChangeCause*MapFrameManager*LayerFrameManager*GoalCounter*FrameEventAggregator*DataMonitor*MapFrameData*LayerFrameData*Clipper*CompositePrimitiveSet*DataLoader*Differ*FixedPrimitiveSet*PrimitiveSubset*Overlay*OverlayAlignment*ImageryMapLayer*SimpleSceneContributor*VectorMapLayer*BasicMapAnimation*MapViewAnimator*BoundsAccumulator*CombinedLayerCollection*ConstrainViewArgs*LatLonCrs*LocationRect*Matrix2D*MapInstrumentationManager*Map*MapHelper*MapMath*MapLocation*MapType*MapTypeChangeArgs*MapTypeCollection*MapTypeId*MapView*MapEventForPrimitiveOverlay*MapQuadrant*PrimitiveOverlayHelper*OverlayBehavior*GeometryGeneralizer*SimplePointPrimitive*SimpleLinePrimitive*SimpleAreaPrimitive*MoveableSimplePointPrimitive*TargetViewChangeArgs*VectorMath*ViewChangeArgs*ZoomLevel*ZoomAroundLocationAnimator*ZoomEventArgs*OverviewMapMode*MapAuthentication*PublicApi*InternalApi*AnonymousEnd

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'matchMedia'
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Internet Explorer 11 should support matchMedia](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia). Therefore, the most likely cause is that the document is being parsed in a [non *full standard* mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode). Probably because you did not specify a doctype at the top of your HTML, e.g.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

As the topmost HTML line.

Another possibility is that you are declaring that the browser should use a compatibility mode, for instance by use of the `http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"` meta tag. If this tag is present, try removing it. If it isn't present, try adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

to ensure that IE is using the latest mode it can. [Read more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275356/ie-compatibility-mode-x-ua-compatible-tag-edge)

Comment: You nailed it!  My asp.net master page had: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />

Comment: @MikeWitt Happy to help. Have a nice 2017!