# How to target IE=EmulateIE7 for IE8 only?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

Now that IE9 has come out, I noticed that the IE=EmulateIE7 trick also affects it.
How can I make it target IE8 only??

So far I tried conditional comments

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
 <![endif]-->
```

But for some reason it does not work (maybe conditional comments dont work with meta tags?). Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the dual mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7, IE=EmulateIE9">
```

as mentioned here:
[Emulate IE7 for IE8 but not for IE9 using "X-UA-Compatible"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413629/emulate-ie7-for-ie8-but-not-for-ie9-using-x-ua-compatible)

Comment: use a comma, not a semi-colon.

Answer (score 3):

I've read that using a semi-colon as the separator doesn't work, and that you should use commas instead, i.e:

content="IE=EmulateIE7, IE=EmulateIE9"

and NOT:

content="IE=EmulateIE7; IE=EmulateIE9"

Comment: Can I use httpd.conf for dual mode. Right now I use like Header add X-UA-Compatible IE=EmulateIE7 Pl. check the question I have asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189817/how-do-i-set-different-options-for-x-ua-compatible-in-apache-for-ie8-and-ie9