# jsTree issues in IE 8,9

Tags: internet-explorer, jstree

We are using the jstree jQuery Plugin to display the role list in a hierarchial format. It works perfectly fine in Firefox browser, but I dont see the tree in I.E. browser. is there any special style changes required for supporting/ displaying the tree in IE 8 and 9?

Thanks in advance,
Priyank

Answer (score 1):

Are you building your `jstree` from html?
Remove your call to `jstree`, effectively leaving your list as plain text; does it render?

If not, you have bigger problems, but if it does I'm willing to bet the tags are just a tiny bit invalid.

I had the same issue where the tree would work in Chrome, Firefox and even IE11/10, but not 9.
I passed my html though a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) and found that some parts of my lists were malformed (even though the browsers displayed them fine if `jstree` wasn't called).

`jstree` likes to remove elements that don't fit.

---

Since your question is vague as to your setup, it might be worth noting that you must use jQuery version 1.11.1, or lower, as >=2 won't even work in 8.

---

Another issue may be that it is rendering in IE7 mode or quirks (you can check this via the developer tools).
Try adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>` at the top of your `<head>` tag.

If it is still stuck in document mode <8 then you are likely running the page in an intranet setting; you'll need to get the server to send `X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge` header, or [change your browser's settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156639/x-ua-compatible-is-set-to-ie-edge-but-it-still-doesnt-stop-compatibility-mode#9624500) to get it to behave.

Comment: Refactor the HTML to make it valid fixed the problem on IE8 for me. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that IE requires more than other browsers is to correctly define the DOCTYPE.

See the solution under:
[jsTree display flaw in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091914/jstree-display-flaw-in-ie8)