# Jstree: hidden nodes remain visible

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jstree

I'm starting with jstree plugin, and I'm having a problem with it.

I don't know why, but nodes are always shown, even if I collapse them.

When tree is loaded, nodes are closed and the tree looks like this:

[image]

I open the first node, and tree looks like this:

[image]

And, when I close(collapse) the previous opened node, it looks like this one (parent node seems closed, but its children are visible):

[image]

jsTree version is pre1.0 stable (downloaded from [here](http://jstree.googlecode.com/files/jstree_pre1.0_stable.zip))

The JSON data I generate with my app are:

```
[
{   "data" : "Parent ...",
    "state" : "closed",
    "attr" : {
        "id": "parentID", 
        "rel": "line", 
        "class": "jstree-unchecked"
    },
    "children": [
                {   "data" : "proposal1 . . .",
                    "state" : "closed",
                    "attr" : { 
                            "id": "prop1", 
                            "rel": "proposal", 
                            "class": "jstree-checked jstree-leaf" 
                            }
                },
                {   "data" : "proposal2 . . .",
                    "state" : "closed",
                    "attr" : { 
                            "id": "prop2", 
                            "rel": "proposal", 
                            "class": "jstree-unchecked jstree-leaf" 
                    }
                }
                ]
}]
```

Finally, jsTree script section to create the tree is:

```
$("#propuestas").jstree({
                "json_data" : {
                    "data" :vewJson,
                    "progressive_render" : true
                }
                ,
                "ui" : {
                        "select_limit" : -1,
                        "real_checkboxes" : true
                        },

                "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data","checkbox", "ui"]

            });
```

Why are parent node *opened*? Why are the children/leaf nodes visible?

Any help is very very appreciated. I'm so stuck with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used your code and created a fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/sJpcs/1/ which is working. Are there any errors throws in your browser console ?

Comment: @MotaBOS, thanks for your answer. I hear something about jsfiddle, it looks like a great tool. In IE8, with Development Tool (F12 key), console does not show anything. Thanks again

Comment: check firefox, press `Ctrl+Shft+J` for error console.

Comment: @MotaBOS, I wrote one simple HTML with local data, and it works well. But my app is not developed for Firefox (only IE) and I cannot reach the page with jsTree. I have one jCarousel and FF shows me an 'script busy' message. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar post/fix here: [display flaw for IE8/9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091914/jstree-display-flaw-in-ie8). It looks like it's a doctype issue.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I was searching in this wonderful site, but I didn't find the post you tell me. Finally I had to implement that requirement by another way, but I vote your answer and tell anyone that takes this problem to try that fix. Thanks again