# Different behavior when using IP address and computer name to access a website

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am puzzled by this. I have a page with a dropdown menu. It behaves correctly in IE 10 and 11 (also in other browsers), but behaves different in IE 9.

I have two ways to access the page of my website: via computer IP address such as:

```
http://123.456.789.12/page.html
```

The other way is through computer name such as:

```
http://computer-name.com/page.html
```

When I use the IP address and move the mouse over the menu, the display is correct (dropdown menu): [image]

However, if using the computer name, I get this: [image]

I cleared cache, verified that they are the same page, etc. I cannot figure out why in IE 9, it has such behavior.

Does anybody know why? Fix?

Thanks and regards.

**Update: This is the head of my page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>           <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>               <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>               <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
 <!--<![endif]-->

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/reset.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />

    <script src="/lib/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/lib/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/lib/jquery-ui-1.10.4/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>

    </head>
```

**Update 2: found the solution at SO!**

[Html 5 Reset (html5reset.org) - X-UA-Compatible doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682827/html-5-reset-html5reset-org-x-ua-compatible-doesnt-work)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html 5 Reset (html5reset.org) - X-UA-Compatible doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682827/html-5-reset-html5reset-org-x-ua-compatible-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of [**smart defaults**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx), which switches the Browser/Document Mode between the two instances of the site.

> In order to preserve compatibility, Internet Explorer ships with
>   smart defaults based on zone evaluation. In the default state, all
>   sites on the public internet display in Internet Explorer Standards
>   mode (Compatibility View off) and all intranet websites display in
>   Internet Explorer 7 Standards mode (Compatibility View on).

Add this to the head of your page:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Comment: I did that but it seems not working. Thanks so much for helping me!