# Meta tag force to use IE Edge or IE8 but not IE9

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, meta-tags

I face 80020101 error issue in ie9 and half of my script classes face this issue so I cannot fix it and my site works well in ie8. How can I force to use IE8 if the browser is IE9 but if the browser version is higher than IE 9, that one should be used.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Web</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=80" />
```

The meta must be the first after the title. But not sure if this will solve the issue 80020101. Not everything will be running in IE9+ if it was using some deep stuff of the IE 8-

To target the edge check this question: [Why does IE9 opens in Document Mode as IE7 standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13949858/1679310)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: If I include both of these metatags, will it eliminate IE9? I mean if a user has IE10, I want my site to use IE=edge, if a user has IE9 then IE8.

Comment: The point is that not ONLY ONE! but even only the first meta tag after title will be used. SO no comments...nothing. Only one tag will decide. If I really needed (intranet) to do some magic, I did some recoginicion on the server and rendered appropriate tag...Conditional simply won't work

Comment: @BerkArslan just use conditional comments: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20289094/1207195

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well you want to force IE 8 when browser is IE 9 and let it *free* when it's a  higher version. You can do it with [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28vs.85%29.aspx):

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=80" />
<![endif]-->
```

This will include `meta` only for IE 8 and will leave it out for any other version. Please note that unless you're facing an IE 9 specific bug then you may have the same issue on higher versions, maybe because IE 8 was broken). To solve this I would rewrite your scripts to work on IE 9 and I would *conditionally include* old scripts when IE 8:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src=oldscript.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<script src=newScript.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: my scripts came from a third party company and it has over 10000 lines of code so I don't want to go through them :). I knew I could use your method but while I research for 80020101 error, I found that comment lines that include "<!--", can also cause this error, so I didn't use this method but I guess I don't have any other option

Comment: yes, 2nd part is just a possible solution but it's not always applicable. About 80020101...there are 1000 reasons for it (may even be a syntax error) but nothing that stops you to add well formed code (so don't worry to add a comment <!-- because it won't break anything!)