# Javascript issue while validating dates

Tags: javascript

In our application,we are using the javascript method, which validates credit card expiry date and returns true if the expiry date is greater than current date. A user reported that the application is not accepting the expiry date 08/2014 in IE 9 browser. When we launched IE in user machine,it opened in IE 9 Compat view browser mode and IE7 Document Standards.The method is failing only for the expiry dates 08/2014 and 09/2014. When we manually changed the browser mode to IE 9 and standards to IE9 ,it worked.I am not able to understand why IE is opening with IE9 Compat view mode and IE 7 standards.Do we need to enforce the IE to always open in IE9?

fnValidateExpiryDate('08/2014','02/20/2014');`

```
function fnValidateExpiryDate(expiryDate , currentDate) {

    var regexp = /^((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(\d{4})$/;

    if (!regexp.test(expiryDate)) {

        return false;
    }

    var userDate = expiryDate.split('/');
    var configDate = currentDate.split('/');
    if (parseInt(userDate[1]) < parseInt(configDate[2])) {
        return false;
    }
    if ((parseInt(userDate[1]) == parseInt(configDate[2])) && (parseInt(userDate[0]) < parseInt(configDate[0]))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The use case provided seems to work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/XRf3T/. How do you generate current date?

Comment: The current date is generated  from DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

Comment: is DateTime some library?

Comment: yes DateTime is C# system library. It generates the date in this format '02/20/2014'

Comment: If `expiryDate` is coming in from user input into a text box you will want to trim off all leading or trailing spaces `expiryDate.replace(/\s/g, '');`

Comment: The trimming  off leading and trailing spaces is already handled and it is invoked before invoking this method.

Comment: You can include MetaTag in your page to enforce IE 9 standards

Refer this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949858/why-does-ie9-opens-in-document-mode-as-ie7-standards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include MetaTag in your page to enforce IE 9 standards

Refer this link
[Why does IE9 opens in Document Mode as IE7 standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949858/why-does-ie9-opens-in-document-mode-as-ie7-standards)