# Internet Explorer renders tablix too large

Tags: internet-explorer, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have designed a report with a tablix. The problem is that in Internet Explorer, the rows of the tablix are too high if the report loads automatically. They are higher than prescribed in the height property, and so are not fully displayed on the page. This only happens in Internet Explorer (I use Version 11). If I reload the content, every is fine.

[image]

The beige rectangle represents the interactive height. 
The green tablix rows use more space and are cut off at the bottom.

Has anyone found a workaround or the reason for the problem? I cannot really prevent the report from loading automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The report was rendered with report viewer in a webform and the problem was that IE opened the page in an outdated document mode (7). In my specific case, this happened because IE detected the page as an intranet page and activated "compatibility view". Check here for more reasons:

[Why does IE9 opens in Document Mode as IE7 standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949858/why-does-ie9-opens-in-document-mode-as-ie7-standards)