# Why does forEach() not work in an iframe in IE11?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, foreach, internet-explorer-11

This question was closed as off-topic, so I've **marked** the *missing* info.

**Specific problem or error** plus **shortest code neccesary:**

The code below doesn't work in IE11, if it's in an iframe of certain websites.
("Certain" is not specific, but I don't have a public demo. I can't make one, until I find the cause in my private code. Still, the question is specific enough to be answered by an expert, that's why I've asked SO instead of a long debugging process without any idea.)

```
['a', 'b'].forEach(function(elem){console.log(elem);});
```

The [error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn720784(v=vs.94).aspx) says that the array doesn't support the forEach method.

**Desired behavior:**

> The forEach() method executes a provided function once per array
>   element. - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: You're going to have to post the code involved for anybody to be able to help.

Comment: I can only guess, since you haven't provided a reproduction.  My guess is the frame issued this command. `delete [].constructor.prototype.forEach`.  That removes the `forEach` method from all arrays.

Comment: Do you check that the [document mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is at least 9? IE8 and earlier versions didn't support `forEach` Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519696/mvc-app-causing-ie9-to-use-older-standards/13524518#13524518).

Comment: @Pointy, code is added.

Comment: @recursive I control the iframe: the mentioned command is not issued. I'm not responsible for the iframe's parent, but if the command is issued by that: it doesn't affect the iframe.

Comment: @dusky The document mode of the form (when not in iframe) is Edge. The document mode of the container website is 7 (caused by a X-UA-compatible meta tag). Does it affect the iframe? It seems to me. I'll read your resources to see if I can avoid this. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, the iframe is affected by the parent's settings (even if I set edge mode explicitly in a meta tag). "IE11 uses Quirks Mode emulation if the top-level page is not in Edge Mode." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955402(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Pointy, I've reworded the question to fit the rules.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"**IE11 uses Quirks Mode emulation** if the top-level page is not in Edge Mode." - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955402(v=vs.85).aspx)

In this mode, arrays don't support the forEach method.

Use a simple **[for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)** instead, or write this right after the title tag of the **parent**:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: Remember, avoid using IE=edge unless you are sure what you are doing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14611264/x-ua-compatible-content-ie-9-ie-8-ie-7-ie-edge http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideIE9.html

Comment: I disagree, I say avoid _not_ using IE=edge :)