# ie conditional comments not working in ie10 browser( ie9, ie8, ie9)

Tags: internet-explorer

I am using Internet Explorer to see designing issues related to ie. So i try to write ie conditional comments for ie special, but its not working. when i refresh the page it behaves like its working(while loading) means the css written for ie 7 works but when it is completely loaded it disappear. I don't know what is really is going into my internet explorer.

I know ie10 has removed conditional comments for it, but lower version should behave with ie conditional comments right ?

I am using window 8 and it has inbuilt ie10 , ie9 , ie8, ie7
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks In advance.

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>

<link href="stylesheets/ie.css" rel="stylesheet">

<![endif]-->
```

CSS cods for ie.css

```
.three_columns { width:500px;}
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly happens in which browser versions? It's unclear to me what the issue is

Comment: i updated again.. hope it helps.. am trying since whole day.. Still issue..

Comment: "Inbuilt" in which way - do you mean IETester? As far as I remember,  conditional comments don't work properly in IETester. They will always "simulate" the most recent version of IE that's installed on the system.

Comment: Any idea how to accomplish ?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but I had the same issue when testing a website in IE8.

I was using IE10 browser and changed the compatibility mode (from developer tools-F12) to `Document mode: 8` and `User agent string: Internet Explorer 8`. The result was that the web page wasn't loading the `shiv` script because I was using conditional comments to target IE versions earlier than 9.

I researched and found out that IE10 dropped conditional comments (duh!), but this also affects the compatibility mode that comes with this browser. So, basically even if you're running in this mode (IE8), IE10 and IE11 ignore all conditional comments and translate them into regular comments, resulting `html5` tags not being recognized since `shiv.js` was not loading.

In a few words, test your website in a *REAL* IE8 browser and not in compatibility mode of IE10 or IE11. You can find many websites through Google that load web pages through a bunch of browsers and devices.

Comment: As a follow-up Microsoft runs [Modern.ie](http://modern.ie/en-us), a site all about testing IE. Good collection of resources and free virtual machine downloads for testing environments. It's a pain they removed conditional comments (yet still boast an "emulation" mode) but it's better than having to keep a bunch of older machines lying around your home or office.

Answer (score 0):

IE 10 switches to IE 7 on Intranet. To change this behaviour see: [X-UA-Compatible is set to IE=edge, but it still doesn't stop Compatibility Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156639/x-ua-compatible-is-set-to-ie-edge-but-it-still-doesnt-stop-compatibility-mode).

For testing you can also switch to whatever engine you want by pressing F12 and changing document compatibility manually.

Comment: I am switching to ie 7 by pressing f12 and changing compatibility manually.. It was working on window 7 but now i have window 8 and its not working

Comment: You must change both compatibility and engine setting. For whatever reason changing only one of them doesn't trigger conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty old but as @otinani already indicated, this is a problem with the compat mode. This mostly happens on intranets in companies but could - in the worst case - occur in production mode to any person that has switched the IE mode.

To make it short: Do not use cond-comments if you want to be safe but use this library I've written for this issue: https://github.com/activenode/IE-Behaviour-Detection-Library