# How to add custom headers in jetty or tomcat... for IE edge emulation?

Tags: internet-explorer, tomcat, internet-explorer-9, jetty

I have just check the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156639/x-ua-compatible-is-set-to-ie-edge-but-it-still-doesnt-stop-compatibility-mode/17672454#17672454) on adding of

```
  <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE9" />
      </customHeaders>
```

If some one can help me with, on how to adding this server parameter for IE if the server is not IIS or Lamp stack, Rather jetty or tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

In jetty you can use the rewrite handler to add a header.

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-handlers.html#rewrite-handler

Or if you are using servlets you can just use a servlet filter, since this is a part of the servlet spec it would work on jetty or tomcat.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html

Comment: Thanks jesse for helping me, will check this