# jQuery Ajax Can't POST (only on IE10)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-10

I have an Ajax code, and it work's, but not in IE10. In the debugger I see that no parameters sent, and no data recived.

I tried to put this inside the `<head`>:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

But it's not helped.

The Code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/unlock.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: { 'password': password, 'file': $("input[name='fileId']").val(), 'keep': ($("input[name='keep']").is(':checked')) ? 'true' : 'false' },
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#locked_div").html('<img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" />');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.charAt(0) == 0) {
            data = data.slice(1);
            $("#locked_div").html('<button id="locked">הורדה נעולה</button><p id="error"></p>');
            $("#error").html(data);
        } else {
            $("#locked_content").slideUp(); 
            $("#prem_message").slideUp(function() {
                $("#dl_section").html(data);
                $("#download").fadeIn('slow');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

What's the problem?

Thanks, and sorry for my English

Comment: Are you getting any Javascript errors?

Comment: @Barmar No, there are no errors in the console

Comment: What version of jQuery?

Comment: Is it at all feasible to move to 1.9.x? IE10 didn't exist when 1.7.2  came out so support is expected to be spotty.

Comment: @Mataniko I tried it on the newest version of jQuery, and it's steal not working

Comment: jQuery 2 removes support for older versions of IE, in that case compatibility mode under IE 10 can break things. There's a bunch of info about setting compatibility mode [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156639/x-ua-compatible-is-set-to-ie-edge-but-it-still-doesnt-stop-compatibility-mode) that might be useful. A little more information is needed at this point, what part of the code doesn't execute, did you try putting breakpoints? You definitely need to upgrade to jQuery to 1.9.x if you want to keep IE 9 and under compatability. If you can set up a fiddle that would be very helpful.

Comment: As others have stated, you can move to jQuery 1.9.x, but you may have to update other plugins that rely on `$.browser`.  This was removed for 1.9.