# Internet Explorer EDGE compatibility problems?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

We are running a website for a client: http://www.avancecarpets.co.za/customiser.php

It was working fine, then all of the sudden on IE it stopped working.  It still works fine on firefox and chrome.

But on IE, it doesn't show the different room options, only the following url: http://www.zdnet.com/search?t=7&mode=rss&tag=mantle_skin;content  which is quite strange.

I've tested and it works perfectly in IE 7 - 10, but the new EDGE emulation is breaking it?  How do I fix this?

Please any help would be appreciated as the client is on my case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156639/x-ua-compatible-is-set-to-ie-edge-but-it-still-doesnt-stop-compatibility-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IE you can force the compatibility mode with this meta tag in the head of your html :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />   <!-- required to force IE Document Mode to latest version -->
```

replace IE=Edge with your targeted IE version : example :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```