# Add meta Tag to head of All Pages in Site

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, meta-tags, global-asax

I need to add a meta tag (To compatible with IE7)

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">`  to all pages of my site.

The site have about 300 pages(.aspx), So I think about some settings to add just one time rather than add it to all the 300 pages.

Is there any settings in IIS?

Or any Way to add the tag in Global.asax?

Does any one have any idea to add the tag somewhere for all pages and not added to the pages one by one?

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156639/x-ua-compatible-is-set-to-ie-edge-but-it-still-doesnt-stop-compatibility-mode#answer-9338959 That seems solved my problem, but generally this is not a way to add meta tag!