# IE11 emulates IE7 even though it's set to EDGE

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

My website has the following settings:

[image]

But IE11 renders the page in IE7 mode:

[image]

This is on a machine with a fresh IE11 install, and it's the first time I'm visiting the website with the browser.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have any other <meta> tags that might be overriding it, or some HTTP response headers?

Comment: If you click the blue links it might tell you why.

Comment: Your DTD is a HTML comment : ), should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Also the `X-UA` should be placed before any `script`, `link`, `style` or any tag, which could affect document mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does moving the X-UA-Compatible  tag to be immediately underneath the  tag make a difference?

See answer by neoswf:

[X-UA-Compatible is set to IE=edge, but it still doesn't stop Compatibility Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156639/x-ua-compatible-is-set-to-ie-edge-but-it-still-doesnt-stop-compatibility-mode)

Cheers,