# Does X-UA-Compatible header override compatibility mode group policy?

Tags: internet-explorer-10, group-policy, x-ua-compatible

My organisation has a group policy that sets IE10 to display all pages in a particular domain in compatibility mode.  If I add the X-UA-Compatible IE=edge HTTP response header to my web server, will this override the group policy?

Basically, which reigns supreme - the group policy setting or the HTTP Response header?

Comment: possible duplicate of [X-UA-Compatible is set to IE=edge, but it still doesn't stop Compatibility Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156639/x-ua-compatible-is-set-to-ie-edge-but-it-still-doesnt-stop-compatibility-mode)

Comment: My question specifically relates to the group policy setting - the question listed above does not specifically address group policy but is a general discussion of IE.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my experience, these settings aren't as "binary" as they appear - you may end up with it "mostly" following the header but with some older behaviours not switched off.

Answer (score 3):

My organization also has a policy as you describe. Everything *.ourdomain.com is treated like an "Intranet" (even though the same domain with www. is used for a public-facing website) and IE 10 has, by default, the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility Mode" checked.

I believe up through IE 9, the group policy overrode the meta tag for sure.

IE 10 seems to behave differently. As long as the `X-UA-Compatible <meta>` tag is at, or very near, the opening  tag, then IE 10 will respect the meta tag above the group policy.

I have just now tested with the HTTP header by adding it to an .htaccess. To my surprise, not only did IE 10 respect it, but also IE 9!

I don't know enough about Microsoft group policies to tell you it will absolutely work in your situation.