# Removing Site from Compatibility View List Programmatically

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-11, compatibility-mode

I have a site that I need to remove from the compatibility view list in both IE9 and IE11.  I need this to happen programmatically in C# code.  A lot of Google searching has not turned up a lot, just the occasional doing it manually instructions, but not really programmatically.  I have seen a lot of doing it via physically adding the headers to the HTML;however, I am unable to go into the HTML to physically do that.  Are there any, any other, ways to programmatically in C# take a site off of the compatibility view list?

I don't have physical access to the HTML or web.config files.  This application is a bought application that I need to programmatically change with C# code to work without compatibility mode. --Hope it helps clarifies what I can and cannot do.

Comment: Have a look at the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156639/x-ua-compatible-is-set-to-ie-edge-but-it-still-doesnt-stop-compatibility-mode)

Comment: @Oskar This is a very in depth answer; however,  I am unable to do it this way via I don't have actual access to the web.config files or the html files.  All I have is C# code that can access and retrieve information from the site.

Comment: Check out this link , my be this help's you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e

Comment: You say that "I have a site". It's not clear to me in that context what "C# code that can access and retrieve information from the site" is supposed to mean, if it doesn't mean that you cannot do something like suggested in all those answers. Why can't you add the headers, if you control the code? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.  I recently, like a few minutes ago, learned that I don't control/own the web page code (it's from a third party).  All I can do is retrieve information from the form objects, and add items (like a new user for example).