# HTML 5 - ie8 moves to quirks mode after page refresh (F5)

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have a bug in which a user which views my web application using IE8 hits F5 (refresh) and from time to time, the paged is rendered incorrectly.

I was able to reproduce it on my dev machine and using IE developer tools I was able to find out that the document mode became Quirks. When I changed the value to "Internet Explorer 8 Standards (Page Default)" the problem is resolved and the layout is back to normal.

**Some technical info:**

1. Normally, the page is loaded as "Internet Explorer 8 Standards (Page Default)".
2. My doctype is: `<!DOCTYPE html>`
3. I have the following meta tag: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`
4. The meta tag is the very first element in the "head" element (since some posts suggested that it should be before any other elements, even before the "title" element.

[image: Snippet of my html "head" element]

**I'll appreciate your help :)**

**Edit:**
I also tried to uncheck the “display all intranet sites in compatibility mode" checkbox.

Comment: Is the DOCTYPE declaration the very first thing in the page? is there any white space before it? any type of content? Found this page https://alastairc.ac/testing/IE_Doctypes/ its really weird, as long as the doctype is in HTML5, IE should go to default mode.

Comment: Its the very first declaration.
I have some white spaces but note that it happen after a page refresh (I just hit F5 few times in a row).

Comment: Stop supporting IE8 and tell them to upgrade.

Comment: Why do you have a ID in the <head> tag? Remove that and also those T&amp;T .. stuff from the <head>.

Comment: your `<meta>` tag seems in after `<head>` and  `<html>` tag put it after `<doctype>` ..or read here more ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156639/x-ua-compatible-is-set-to-ie-edge-but-it-still-doesnt-stop-compatibility-mode

Comment: @slime - can't. we have an enterprise client which requires it. This was one of their requirements..

Comment: @António Regadas - still no good. Removed them both and the issue continues.

Comment: Can you share the URL so i can run it too in a IE8 VM?

Comment: I'm gonna say that the compatibility mode setting in IE is causing your problems. Try turning it off and seeing if it does anything.

Comment: @António Regadas - sorry. I can't due to legal constraints :(

Comment: Notice any changes if you change the doctype to html4?
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

Comment: @slime - tried that also.

Comment: Move the meta tag so it comes after the title. Some users have reported that being the fix to this problem.

Comment: @António Regadas - still, no luck.

Comment: @slime - no luck. Moving right after the title didn't help.

Comment: Its strange the fact that it only happens when you refresh the page... does it only triggers quirks mode in IE8? Is 9 ok? clearing the browser cache doesn't help?

Comment: @António Regadas:
1. Clearing the cache doesn't work.
2. I don't have IE9 machine. I can load a VM but it will take me a day. I've tried on IE10 but it doesn't reproduce.

Comment: @nadavy Can you reduce your page to a degree that your legal constraints are no longer an issue, and the issue is still reproducible?

Comment: Why did you upload an image of your code? Just copy/paste the code right into your question. I can barely read that, and if I wanted to try your code on my own machine I don't have anything to copy/paste from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a research, I saw that this issue is reproduced in a simple HTML page ("Hello World" style).
Further research reveled that our IE8 virtual machine template was infected by adware which injected a script to the page, which in turn modified the DOM.

The issue was resolved as soon as I've cleaned the adware.