# Sphinx generated html pages look different when pulled to a NAS drive git repository

Tags: python, git, python-sphinx

I created some documentation using Sphinx on my local drive. I then initialised a `git` repository on a network drive, and `fetched` my work from my local drive so that I can share my documentation with colleagues.

However, the HTML pages on the network drive look very different (in a bad way). The buttons and icons look awful or are missing.

Any idea why this might be? Is it to do with git? sphinx?

**Update**
I checked the console and compared the output for both the local and network files. On the network file, there is a message that says

> HTML1203: ****.local has been configured to run in Compatibility View through Group Policy.

There is also another message that says

> The attached page targets document mode 7. Some console APIs and
>   features may not be available.

Could either of those be causing the issue?

**Update 2**
The css files that Sphinx generates is located in /css/theme.css

Below is a screenshot from the network tab of the developer tools:
[image]

Comment: Have you looked in your browser's dev panel? I'd guess the CSS isn't loading. What is actually *serving* the files?

Comment: @jonrsharpe How would I know if my CSS isn't loading? The files are all just sat in a location on the LAN. So, I open it up by going to the network location for the repository and navigating to the index.html file.

Comment: Look up the instructions for opening the developer panel in whatever browser you're using. Go to the Network tab. Reload the page. Read the results and any messages in the console. You will probably need an actual web server to provide the CSS files, not just place them in the same directory.

Comment: Neither of those tells us whether css files are being loaded. Do you even have external stylesheets? What about the data in the network tab, as I asked for; any 4xx or 5xx responses?

Comment: @jonrsharpe there are no 4xx or 5xx responses. I've updated the question with a screenshot of the network tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the technicalities, but the problem occurred because I was using an UNC path to a NAS drive.

The solution was to either map the network drive and open the HTML file from the mapped drive or to use the command `explorer index.html` to open the file.

Answer (score 3):

Try a non-IE web browser, like Chrome or Firefox. Else look at these three possible fixes:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9487fead-95e6-4af7-821d-e14a9cba7631/html-1203-domain-has-been-configured-to-run-in-compatibility-view-through-group-policy?forum=win10itproapps
- [X-UA-Compatible is set to IE=edge, but it still doesn't stop Compatibility Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156639/x-ua-compatible-is-set-to-ie-edge-but-it-still-doesnt-stop-compatibility-mode)