# Raphael JS performance in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, raphael

Raphael's performance in IE8 is significantly worse than in IE7 or IE6.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/t5NGF/

The example above renders nearly 10 times slower in IE8 than in IE7.  Activating IE8's compatibility mode, the performance matches IE7.

Why is IE8 so much slower than IE7/IE6 when using Raphael and is there anything to be done to improve the performance?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's not much you can do about this.

Raphael renders graphics in SVG for most browsers, but in VML when running under IE6, IE7 and IE8. VML is a vector graphics language that Microsoft created for IE before SVG had been defined as a standard.

The bad news is that IE8's VML engine is significantly slower than that in IE6 and IE7, and certain features in Raphael hit those slow spots particularly badly. Vector graphic performance in IE8 is bad. It's just an unfortunate fact.

A [tip I found here](http://www.netzgesta.de/cvi/faq.php) suggests that you *might* be able to get some performance increase by setting IE8 to use its IE7-compatibility mode. I haven't tried it yet, and to be honest I hesitate to suggest this as there are any number of reasons not to want to do use compatibility mode, but a large part of the reason for Raphael's poor performance in IE8 is down to [some fairly significant changes to the VML language](http://ajaxian.com/archives/the-vml-changes-in-ie-8) that were made between IE7 and IE8. Going into compatibility mode *might* make the browser switch to the IE7 version of the VML language, and thus avoid those issues.

As I said, I'd try to avoid this option if at all possible, as compatibility mode has a lot of issues, but if you really can't make things work satisfactorily any other way, you could give it a try. Note, if you do use this solution, be careful to only activate it for IE8; you really don't want IE9 or IE10 going into IE7 mode if you can avoid it!

Answer (score 0):

the right way is

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7, IE=9">
```

because ie9 had implemented svg ，so if you write :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

then ie9 fall down to ie7

more info in [Emulate IE7 for IE8 but not for IE9 using "X-UA-Compatible"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413629/emulate-ie7-for-ie8-but-not-for-ie9-using-x-ua-compatible)