# Background and page tabs disappear in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, blogger

My blog works fine in IE10 and in Chrome, but when viewed in IE8, it initially loads correctly but then the background and page tabs and names disappear. It's weird because my test blog works fine and I'm not sure what I changed that would effect it.

test blog - damianp1.blogspot.co.uk

real blog with problem - sthelensbirds.blogspot.co.uk

I'm not even sure where to look to try and find the problem. I'm thinking of going through the code line by line to try and find any differences but if anyone could let me know where abouts to look I'd be very grateful.

Cheers, Damian.

Comment: Weird as it may seem, it seems to happen when ``www.blogblog.com/1kt/transparent/black50.png`` gets loaded. btw the site also looks fine in IE7 ..just IE8 is bogged out !

Comment: btw your site is loading 2 jquery versions: 1.10.2 which is then overwritten by 1.7.1, not that i think this is causing the problem..

Comment: I've been working on this for hours and have just found something. I made a duplicate blog using the html from the working test blog, and went through each setting I'd applied to the real blog one by one and checking ie8 every time. When I disabled mobile view the problem appeared. Re-enabling mobile view doesn't fix the problem. I've checked what changes disabling mobile view makes to the html and it seems to change lots of things. Is there any way to isolate the problem?

Comment: try removing black50.png from the css ..i know it sounds stupid, just a crazy idea. All more likely it seems that somewhere towards the end of the site loading, an action/load occurs that changes things. Images disappear systematically at the ``end`` of load cycle. Either a last js/css getting loaded, or a document.ready, setimeout changing things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted it - sort of! Thanks for the tips Robert. I found some code that makes the browser emulate IE7 and stuck it in here...

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile'>
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum
scale=1.0'  
name='viewport'/>
<b:else/>
<meta content='width=1100' name='viewport'/><meta content='IE=EmulateIE7' http-
equiv='X-UA-
Compatible'/>
</b:if>
```

The

```
<meta content='IE=EmulateIE7' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>
```

is the bit I added. The blog now works correctly on IE8.

It's working, but have I put the code in the right place? Is there any better way of sorting this?

Edit - This code makes IE8 emulate IE7, but leaves IE9, IE10, and chrome alone...

```
<meta content='IE=7,IE=9, IE=10, chrome=1' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413629/emulate-ie7-for-ie8-but-not-for-ie9-using-x-ua-compatible) where I found it.

Comment: Actually that solution isn't so good as it now doesn't work as well as it did in IE10. How do I code so that if the browser is IE8, it does the above, but otherwise works as normal?

Comment: I used this.. <!--[if IE 8]>

    <meta content='IE=EmulateIE7' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>

    <![endif]-->
It seems to work in both IE10 and IE8 ok now. Is what I've done ok?

Comment: I think this worked in the end...                                    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,IE=9, IE=10, chrome=1" />