# IE10 issue with telerik controls

Tags: asp.net

i am having problem with the telerik controls. Telerik dropdowns are working fine with IE8 and IE9 but throwing java script exception with IE10. Can anyone answer?

Comment: Perhaps you should post what the exceptions are? I also suggest you ask the company behind telrik.

Comment: There is a issue with older versions of the telerik controls. Make sure you have the latest version.

Comment: exception is"Unhandled exception at line 155, column 2 in http://localhost:9939/FYBAVPA/ScriptResource.axd?d=ruQmDrsU4jDrjA2qjU9mdVvmfEoKexqpjU6_DnePnDsUc4p8bXMNOOEP0cA-IjCSuK0bUiUkxyDMD0Bq9mlZfCFHeEuv7EtGstHGwEcgDOTtDhbeWl3USd1tFTtJNTTVt1QmU2RGBEZXIXALBd0HmQ2&t=4652149b

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'documentElement' of undefined or null reference"

Answer (score 0):

if you are developing , you can hit F12 and trigger the dev tools ,or use the meta tags to force a mode, I've had varrying results, about two years ago had a bunch of IE9 problems with a Q1 2010 edition of the controls and it only partly fixed the probem in IE9, but the controls worked exactly right in IE8.

[X-UA-Compatible is set to IE=edge, but it still doesn't stop Compatibility Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156639/x-ua-compatible-is-set-to-ie-edge-but-it-still-doesnt-stop-compatibility-mode)

[Emulate IE7 for IE8 but not for IE9 using "X-UA-Compatible"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413629/emulate-ie7-for-ie8-but-not-for-ie9-using-x-ua-compatible)

to force latest version behavior, put a meta tag in your page head, preferable one of the first tags in the page head

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: thanks steven..but i have applied this solution but the problem is still there..plz sugggest another one.